# crashing application in simulator

Tags: iphone, debugging

I am new to iPhone SDK. I have activated zombie and guard Malloc also. When I am playing with my application for 10 or 15 minutes, it crashes.

Now when my application crashed, console gives me some useful output, but I am not able to understand what it wants to say. So please help me.

Here is output of console :

> GuardMalloc[GNG-4042]: Failed to VM allocate 400000 bytes
>   GuardMalloc[GNG-4042]: Explicitly trapping into debugger!!!

Now what should i do? Please help me. Thanking you.

Comment: please suggest me what should i do?

Comment: Make sure you release all allocated objects. Please post source code so we can look it over.

Comment: problem is that it crashes randomly so how can i post code?

Comment: but thanks to guide that caused by memory leak...

Answer (score 0):

Try profiling your code with the Instruments tool of Xcode to detect and fix memory leaks. Here is a good tutorial on using this tool: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial

Comment: i checked my code and i got leak.Here is link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898537/getting-leak-from-web-service...but i can't remove...